# How to fix bed slats?

Tags: bedroom

I'm wondering if there is an easy but reliable way to fix this slat under my mattress (see attached image). It's an Ikea bed.

Any suggestion? I was thinking of flat metal pieces screwed into the wood on each side like some kind of splint..

[image]

Comment: Just replace it. Or send that picture to Ikea and have them replace it, as it was a blatantly defective piece of wood for the job due to that knot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metal plates will be nice and fast to repair that, but in my opinion, You need one for each side and - the longer the better. Some glue for wood may be nice to use before fitting.
Remember not to use too-long screws to avoid matress damage. Alternatively You can use bolts and drill holes for them before fitting together.

Optional fix can be done by removing all of these wooden bars (these come bound together from Ikea as I recall - my kids got similar beds) and remove broken one with new one (You can buy it in probably every shop like Castorama in Eastern Europe). Replacing this would be most elegant way, I guess.

Comment: I like the swap out option you've described.  They can also put a few more slats in, to increase the weight bearing capacity.

Comment: I've put a metal bar on top and another below plus some glue, seems to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Glue the existing slat back together.
2. Reinforce it from the bottom with a piece of dimensional lumber (60cm x 2cm x 2+cm)
3. Glue and screw that lumber to the bottom of the slat -- it  won't affect the mattress, as the reinforcement is below the bed.

Metal plates are likely either to bend or to weaken the already thin slat.

Alternatively, you could adjust the other slats and just not use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a good quality wood glue and clamp it until it's dried. That is likely all you need. Reinforcing might be needed, but I doubt it.